# Перемещение объекта по контуру элемента

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Пытаюсь реализовать перемещение объекта по контуру элемента. Код:

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  var prevX = null;
  var prevY = null;

  //true = up, false = down
  var UpDown = null;

  //true = rigth, left = false
  var LeftRight = null;
  $('.box').css("left", 300 + 'px');
  $('.box').css("top", 100 + 'px');
  $('.box .circle').css("left", 256 + 'px');
  $('.box .circle').css("top", 260 + 'px');

  $('.box').draggable();

  $('.box .circle').draggable({
    axis: "y",
    snap: ".box",
    snapMode: "outer",

    drag: function(event, ui) {
      update(event, ui)
    },
    stop: function() {
      reset
    }
  });

  function update(event, ui) {

    var circle_X = ui.position.left;
    var circle_Y = ui.position.top;

    //размеры внешнего div
    var div_height = $(".box").outerHeight();
    var div_width = $(".box").outerWidth();

    //размеры круга
    var circle_height = $(event.target).outerHeight();
    var circle_width = $(event.target).outerWidth();

    $("li:nth-child(1)").text("CIRCLE SIZE: " + circle_width + "x" + circle_height);

    $("li:nth-child(2)").text("DIV SIZE: " + div_width + "x" + div_height);

    $("li:nth-child(3)").text("CIRCLE POS:" + circle_X + "," + circle_Y);


    //UpDown
    if (prevY == null) {
      prevY = event.pageY;
    } else {
      if (prevY > event.pageY) {
        UpDown = true;
        prevY = event.pageY;
      } else {
        UpDown = false;
        prevY = event.pageY;
      }
    }

    //LeftRight
    if (prevX == null) {
      prevX = event.pageX;
    } else {
      if (prevX > event.pageX) {
        LeftRight = false;
        prevX = event.pageX;
      } else {
        LeftRight = true;
        prevX = event.pageX;
      }
    }

    //#######################
    if (UpDown) {
      $("li:nth-child(4)").text("UpDown: UP");
    } else {
      $("li:nth-child(4)").text("UpDown: DOWN");
    }

    if (LeftRight) {
      $("li:nth-child(5)").text("LeftRight: RIGHT");
    } else {
      $("li:nth-child(5)").text("LeftRight: LEFT");
    }
    // #####################

    //верхняя граница
    var upper_border = -circle_height;

    //нижняя граница
    var bottom_border = div_height;

    //левая граница
    var left_border = -circle_width;

    //правая граница
    var right_border = div_width;

    //верхняя граница

    if (upper_border <= circle_Y) {
      if (left_border <= circle_X | right_border >= circle_X) {
        if (!UpDown) {
          $(".circle").draggable("option", "axis", "y");
        } else {
          if (LeftRight != null) {
            $(".circle").draggable("option", "axis", "x");
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (bottom_border >= circle_Y) {

      if (left_border <= circle_X | right_border >= circle_X) {
        if (UpDown) {
          $(".circle").draggable("option", "axis", "y");
        } else {
          if (LeftRight != null) {
            $(".circle").draggable("option", "axis", "x");
          }
        }
      }
    }



  }

  function reset() {
    prevX = null;
    prevY = null;
    UpDown = null;
    LeftRight = null;
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 260;
  width: 256;
}
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.myclass {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div class="box">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1d63440848ca3eaa0a55ed77a2300997?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
  <div class="circle">123</div>
</div>

<div>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</div>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что не удается переместить объект за одно перетаскивание в противоположный угол (расположенный напротив по диагонали). Так же при перемещении из одного угла в другой объект "телепортируется" в исходное положение (при длительном перетаскивании это выражается в мерцании). Помогите устранить ошибки / предложите другое решение / библиотеку.